# How do I listen to multiple endpoints from a single file in NextJS api?

Tags: next.js

What I am trying to do is to place something like `[*path].ts` inside my api folder in NextJS an listen to all endpoints that might come like `http://localhost:3000/api/playlist/2331` or `http://localhost:3000/api/account/12` in order to make the call to another server in the same format by extracting method, path, body, query and create a new request.

This is what I have now in that file but is never triggered

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    export default function handler(req, res) {
      const {
        method,
        body,
        query,
        query: { path },
      } = req;
    
      console.log('Requested method:', method);
      console.log('Requested path:', path);
      console.log('Request body:', body);
      console.log('Query parameters:', query);
    
      // Create the URL for the request to the other server
      const apiUrl = `http://localhost:3001/api/${path}`;
    
      // Make a request to the other server
      axios({
        method: method, // Use the same method as the original request
        url: apiUrl, // Use the constructed URL
        data: body, // Pass the extracted body
        params: query, // Pass the extracted query parameters
      })
        .then((response) => {
          // Handle the response from the other server
          console.log('Response from the other server:', response.data);
    
          // Return the response to the original request
          res.status(200).json({ message: 'API route catch-all' });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Handle any errors that occur during the request
          console.error('Error:', error);
    
          // Return an error response to the original request
          res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred' });
        });
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to add [...] to the route to match any path?